# Python dateutil parser fails

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I am attempting to parse the following date strings obtained from email headers:

```
from dateutil import parser
d1 = parser.parse('Tue, 28 Jun 2011 01:46:52 +0200')
d2 = parser.parse('Mon, 11 Jul 2011 10:01:56 +0200 (CEST)')
d3 = parser.parse('Wed, 13 Jul 2011 02:00:01 +0000 (GMT+00:00)')
```

The third one fails; am I missing something obvious?

Comment: have you tried `parser.parse('...', fuzzy=True)`?

Comment: phimuemue, add that as an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: eryksun, that is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried `parser.parse('...', fuzzy=True)`? (I suppose it works :))

Comment: Yes it works. The problem is the extra "+00:00" after "GMT", as pointed out below. The "fuzzy" option ignores this.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to [parsedatetime](http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/) library.

```
In [16]: import parsedatetime.parsedatetime as pdt

In [17]: p = pdt.Calendar()

In [18]: p.parse("Wed, 13 Jul 2011 02:00:01 +0000 (GMT+00:00)")
Out[18]: ((2011, 7, 20, 0, 0, 0, 2, 201, -1), 3)
```

Comment: But is it correct? I have difficulty interpreting the tuple. Where is the "13", for example?

Comment: It seems that this parser is confused and thinks the "Wed" refers to tomorrow July 20, which is the closest Wednesday.

Comment: Looks like `parsedatetime` always takes future dates. it has a comment in the source code: `# if that day and month have already passed in this year, then increment the year by 1`