# Python pytz Converting a timestamp (string format) from one timezone to another

Tags: python, timezone, timestamp, pytz

I have a timestamp with timezone information in string format and I would like to convert this to display the correct date/time using my local timezone. So for eg... I have

```
timestamp1 = 2011-08-24 13:39:00 +0800
```

and I would like to convert this to say timezone offset +1000 to dsiplay

```
timestamp2 = 2011-08-24 15:39:00 +1000
```

I have tried using pytz but couldnt find many examples showing how to use the offset information. One other link that I found on stackoverflow which depicts this exact problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python). I was hoping there was some better way I could handle this using pytz. Thanks for all suggestions in advance :).

**UPDATE**

Thanks Cixate. I just found the solution which is very similar to yours. Found these links helpful - [LINK1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python) and [LINK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729902/python-dateutil-parser-fails)

Posting the solution for everyones benefit

```
from datetime import datetime
import sys, os
import pytz
from dateutil.parser import parse

datestr = "2011-09-09 13:20:00 +0800"
dt = parse(datestr)
print dt
localtime = dt.astimezone (pytz.timezone('Australia/Melbourne'))
print localtime.strftime ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
2011-09-09 15:20:00
```

Comment: Consider marking Cixate's answer as correct by clicking its checkbox, since your final solution is close to Cixate's suggestion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[datetime.astimezone](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) will do your basic conversion once you have a datetime object. If you're trying to get a datetime object from a string, pip install [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) and it's as simple as:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> from dateutil.tz import tzoffset
>>> dt = parse('2011-08-24 13:39:00 +0800')
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 24, 13, 39, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 28800))
>>> dt.astimezone(tzoffset(None, 3600))
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 24, 6, 39, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
```

Comment: Thanks Cixate..I just got the solution using dateutil.parser and datetime.astimezone. My solution is a bit different to yours. Forgive my ignorance, but could you please elaborate on how you retrieve the timezone information using "tzoffset(None, 3600)"

Comment: In your example you wanted to translate to an offset of "+1000", unfortunately I read that as "+0100" but the principal is the same. The first parameter of tzoffset() is a name, which can be None if you don't care to know it. The second is the offset from UTC in seconds. So 3600 for 1 hour or 36000 for 10 hours.

Comment: Thanks Cixate for the explanation.